# Problem with `\expandafter` and `csname`

Tags: macros, csname

Above there is a code that I would like to factorize more. I would to define the two macros `\exercice` and `\topic` in a similar way that I do with the special `\@init@new@exo` but I fail for the moment. I'm missing something with `\expandafter` and `csname`...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand\@init@new@exo[1]{
        \pgfkeys{
            /#1@keys/.is family,
            /#1@keys,
                pts/.initial  = {}, % Render the subject or not
                src/.initial  = {}  % Number of the exam

        }

        \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1@number\endcsname{Nb for #1}
    }

    \@init@new@exo{topic}
    \@init@new@exo{exercice}

    \newcommand\exercice[1][]{%
        \begingroup
            \pgfkeys{/exercice@keys, #1}
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/exercice@keys/pts}{\exercice@points}
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/exercice@keys/src}{\exercice@source}
            exercice \exercice@number{}
            (\exercice@points{} pts) 
            [Source :\exercice@source{}] 
        \endgroup
    }

    \newcommand\topic[1][]{%
        \begingroup
            \pgfkeys{/topic@keys, #1}
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/topic@keys/pts}{\topic@points}
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/topic@keys/src}{\topic@source}
            topic \topic@number{}
            (\topic@points{} pts) 
            [Source :\topic@source{}] 
        \endgroup
    }
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\exercice[pts = 1, src = Imaginaire]

\exercice

\topic[pts = 1, src = Imaginaire]

\topic[pts = 2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you're after... Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Werner Yes that's it ! In the command  `\@init@new@exo`, I do twice the same thing (and in reality I would like to do that 5 times). But I can't do the same thing for the two commands `\exercice` and `\topic` using `\expandafter` and `\csname`. If you look at `\exercice` and `\topic`, you will see that their codes are very similar.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR “Exercice” is French.

Comment: @projetmbc The codes are completely identical, except for the keyword (exercice and topic). I'm not sure what's the reason for defining different sets of keys when they are the same for each kind.

Comment: @egreg Oops. That was bad of me; thanks for pointing it out. I've deleted the comment.

Comment: @egreg David Carlisle gives the solution.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR French fogs are not touchy. ;-)

Comment: @projetmbc This doesn't change the fact that defining different sets of keys is useless.

Comment: @egreg Indeed EXERCISES are inside TOPICS so they do not have the same semantics meaning. This is why I need different sets of keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this arranges all the csname construction to happen first so it is not intermingled with the pgf parsing.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter
    \newcommand\@init@new@exo[1]{%%
        \pgfkeys{
            /#1@keys/.is family,
            /#1@keys,
                pts/.initial  = {}, % Render the subject or not
                src/.initial  = {}  % Number of the exam

        }%%
%%
        \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1@number\endcsname{Nb for #1}%%
    }

    \@init@new@exo{topic}
    \@init@new@exo{exercice}

\newcommand\zz[1]{\expandafter\@zz
                    \csname#1\expandafter\endcsname
                    \csname#1@points\expandafter\endcsname
                    \csname#1@source\expandafter\endcsname
                    \csname#1@number\endcsname
                    {#1}}

\newcommand\@zz[5]{%
    \newcommand#1[1][]{%
        \begingroup
            \pgfkeys{/#5@keys, ##1}%%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/#5@keys/pts}{#2}%%
            \pgfkeysgetvalue{/#5@keys/src}{#3}%%
            #5 #4{} %%
            (#2{} pts)
            [Source :#3{}] %%
        \endgroup
    }%%
}


\zz{exercice}
\zz{topic}


\makeatother



\begin{document}

\exercice[pts = 1, src = Imaginaire]

\exercice

\topic[pts = 1, src = Imaginaire]

\topic[pts = 2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this technical solution that will take me a long time to find ! :-)

Comment: Is there an easy way to allow the use of more than 9 arguments with @zz ? I need to use more keys in my API.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the definition of the command in the “init” phase:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse,chngcntr}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\initkeys}{mo}
 {
  \newcounter{#1}
  \IfValueT{#2} { \counterwithin{#1}{#2} }
  \projetmbc_init_keys:n { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \projetmbc_init_keys:n
 {
  \keys_define:nn { projetmbc/#1 }
   {
    pts .tl_set:c = l_projetmbc_#1_pts_tl,
    src .tl_set:c = l_projetmbc_#1_src_tl,
   }
  \exp_args:Nc \NewDocumentCommand {#1} { O{} }
   {
    \refstepcounter{#1}
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { projetmbc/#1 } { ##1 }
    #1 ~ \use:c { the#1 } ~
    \tl_if_empty:cF { l_projetmbc_#1_pts_tl }
     {
      \c_space_tl
      ( \tl_use:c { l_projetmbc_#1_pts_tl } ~ pts)
     }
    \tl_if_empty:cF { l_projetmbc_#1_src_tl }
     {
      \c_space_tl
      [Source: ~ \tl_use:c { l_projetmbc_#1_src_tl } ]
     }
    \group_end:
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\initkeys{exercice}
\initkeys{topic}[exercice]


\begin{document}

\exercice[pts = 1, src = Imaginaire]

\exercice

\topic[pts = 1, src = Imaginaire]

\topic[pts = 2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know a good source for learning $\LaTeX{}$3 `expl3` language ? I really like the way things are implemented.

Comment: @projetmbc I learned it by perusing `interface3.pdf` and looking at `expl3` code .